# Change DIV position to static section of DOM

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, position, css-position

I have a vue app where i created some methods to move my div 'toolbox' into a different section of the DOM. Currently, the DIV loads on the bottom right of the screen and its static, it doesn't move if I scroll the page.

The methods I created are trying to achieve the same thing, but moving the DIV to "Top Left", "Top Right", "Bottom Left", and I'm having some issues finding the right px value to give to given functions. Does anyone know if there is a better way to do this?

My code:

```
  <button @click="changePositionTopLeft">Move Top Left</button>
  <button @click="changePositionTopRight">Move Top Right</button>
  <button @click="changePositionBottomLeft">Move Bottom Left</button>


methods: {
changePositionTopLeft() {
  const divPosition = document.getElementById('sdk-ts-root')
  divPosition.style.left = '200px'
  divPosition.style.top = '200px'
},
changePositionTopRight() {
  const divPosition = document.getElementById('sdk-ts-root')
  divPosition.style.right = '400px'
  divPosition.style.top = '400px'
},
changePositionBottomLeft() {
  const divPosition = document.getElementById('sdk-ts-root')
  divPosition.style.left = '400px'
  divPosition.style.bottom = '400px'
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

When using Vue (or any other similar library like React, Svelte etc.) you should not interact with the DOM directly, but rather create data bindings which will update you HTML automatically.

This is how it should be done with the "Vue way":

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,

  },
  computed: {
    style() {
      return `top: ${this.top}px; right: ${this.right}px; bottom: ${this.bottom}px; left: ${this.left}px;`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changePositionTopLeft() {
      this.top = 200
      this.left = 200
    },
    changePositionTopRight() {
      this.top = 400
      this.right = 400
    },
    changePositionBottomLeft() {
      this.bottom = 400,
        this.left = 400
    },
    reset() {
      this.top = 0;
      this.right = 0;
      this.bottom = 0;
      this.left = 0;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.el {
  position: absolute;
  
  /* some styling */
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div :style="style" class="el">DIV</div>
    <button @click="changePositionTopLeft">Move Top Left</button>
    <button @click="changePositionTopRight">Move Top Right</button>
    <button @click="changePositionBottomLeft">Move Bottom Left</button>
    <button @click="reset">Reset</button>
    top: {{top}} right: {{right}} top: {{bottom}} left: {{left}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and you are right, I should adopt this format for my vue app. The positioning of the DIV still don't work as expected. Mainly my question is if there is a default value of 'px' to set the div to a top left/right, or bottom left/right.